# How do I change the border color of 2 divs at once using the hover effect

Tags: html, css, hover

How can I change the border-color of my outer div `#refdocs_main` while also changing the bottom border color of my div `#refdocs_container`? Right now, only the outer container's border is colored on hover; how can I get both effects using CSS simultaneously?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nb8cC/
And what I've tried so far:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="refdocs_main">
        <div id="refdocs_container"><input type="text" id="refdocs">
        </div>
        <div id="refdocs_wrapper">
            <div id="refdocs_list">
                <ul></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>          
</body>
```

CSS

```
#refdocs {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

#refdocs_main {
    border: 1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    width: 179px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

#refdocs_main:hover {
    border-color: rgb(128,128,128);
}

#refdocs_container {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    height: 20px;
}

#refdocs_wrapper{
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#refdocs_list {
    width: 100%;
}

#refdocs_list ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#refdocs_list li {
    cursor: default;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```css
#refdocs_main:hover, #refdocs_main:hover #refdocs_container {
    border-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
```

By adding `#refdocs_main:hover #refdocs_container` you enable the border on `#refdocs_container` to change only when `#refdocs_main` is being hovered.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nb8cC/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
#refdocs_main:hover #refdocs_container {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

to your css stylesheet.

This reads when `#refdocs_main` is hovered over then for the `#refdocs_container` element apply the following changes.